# cylindrical coordinate point in origin

Tags: opengl, mathematics

I have a camera which has the following attributes:

- pos (position of the camera in the scene)
- look(either direction in which camera will face, or target vector)
- up vector( y axis)

I am using cylindrical coordinates system for moving camera around centre of scene. my question is 'how can I find look vector of the camera in a such a way that it will be pointing out in the origin of the scene under 45 degree?'.

[image]

According to [this](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-do-you-rotate-the-camera-down-to-45-degrees-no-matter-what-direction-youre-facing-solved.364279/) thread there is not such a way.

> And you can never look directly down at the focal point, no matter how high up you go.

P.S: I need somehow to get look vector if it's possible.

Thank you for you attention

Comment: I dont see a contradiction between what you want (to always look at 45degrees) and the quote. Please clarify your problem.

Comment: how can I point camera to an angle 45 degree to the origin using cylindrical coordinate. Is correct the following approach look = (mcenterOfScene-look) *(cos (pi / 4), sin (pi/4),1) ?

Comment: How come you have "look" on both sides of your equation?

Comment: I see I am wrong, but how can I move guess that vector, I suppose it's (r,0,z) ?

Comment: in other word i need when I move camera, look vector always to stay under 45 degree above origin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right! It is only possible if `height == radius`

Further Information - let there be horizontal angle `t Degree` of your green sector in image above.

```
camPos( x = r * cos(t * pi/180 ), y = sin(t * pi/180 ), z=z)
```

multiplying with `pi/180` makes it radian, so be careful.

Looking vector:

```
[x,y,z] = [focus.x - camPos.x, focus.y - camPos.y, focus.z - camPos.z]
```